# Is this an appropriate way of populating dimension table with unique values?

Tags: mysql, database, data-warehouse, star-schema

Would the following script be appropriate for populating the date_dim table? I'm using sqlalchemy to populate a temporary table in MySQL with a PANDAS DataFrame. The purpose for the SQL script below is to populate dates_dim with the values of dates_dim_temp if they are not already there. I also intend to create new primary keys for new entries into date_dim but want to check whether I am on the right track with this script before proceeding:

```
INSERT INTO date_dim  (id, created_at, week_day, month_day, month_num, `year`) 
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM date_dim_temp 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM date_dim_temp ddt JOIN date_dim dd ON  dd.created_at = ddt.created_at);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the join in the subquery of `NOT EXISTS` if you only need to check the existence of the column of the column `created_at`:

```
INSERT INTO date_dim (id, created_at, week_day, month_day, month_num, `year`) 
SELECT DISTINCT ddt.*
FROM date_dim_temp ddt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM date_dim dd WHERE dd.created_at = ddt.created_at);
```

Also if there is a `UNIQUE` constraint for `created_at` in `date_dim` then you don't need `NOT EXISTS`. Use `INSERT IGNORE`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO date_dim (id, created_at, week_day, month_day, month_num, `year`) 
SELECT DISTINCT ddt.*
FROM date_dim_temp ddt
```

This will reject also any other rows that would violate any existing constraint.

Answer (score 1):

YOu don't need the join in the NOT EXISTS. Also is the distinct necessary?

```
INSERT INTO date_dim  (id, created_at, week_day, month_day, month_num, `year`) 
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM date_dim_temp t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM date_dim d WHERE  d.created_at = t.created_at);
```